# ReportViewer multiple result of listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, reportviewer

I have to make a Report with a list box where multiple results are selected

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHcHr.png)

but when I get to the datatable I do not know how to make it show the result of the different values. Selected.
This is my code...

```
protected void CargaReporte(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        dsReportes.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIODataTable dt = new dsReportes.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIODataTable();
        dsReportesTableAdapters.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIOTableAdapter da = new dsReportesTableAdapters.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIOTableAdapter();
        ReportDataSource RD = new ReportDataSource();
        List<dynamic> lst = new List<dynamic>();
        if (ddUsu.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in ddUsu.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    da.Fill(dt, int.Parse(ddUsu.SelectedValue));
                    lst.Add(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            da.Fill(dt, int.Parse(ddUsu.SelectedValue == "" ? "0" : ddUsu.SelectedValue));
        }
        divReporte.Visible = true;

        RD.Value = lst.ToArray();
        RD.Name = "dbCalendarioEventos";
        rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RD);
        rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReporteCalendarioEventos.rdlc";
        rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Reportes\Calendario\ReporteCalendarioEventos.rdlc";
        rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

How can I fill out the report with two or more results?

Comment: I cannot see any image on clicking the link. Can you plz confirm?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHcHr.png  Is an image of the combobox I attached the url of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Create an additional DataTable to save the information set after the path through the foreach and so I can get the result I share part of the code.

```
string participante = (txtParticipante.Value == "" ? " " : txtParticipante.Value);
        dsReportes.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIODataTable dt = new dsReportes.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIODataTable();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        dsReportesTableAdapters.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIOTableAdapter da = new dsReportesTableAdapters.SP_REPORTE_EVENTOS_CALENDARIOTableAdapter();
        ReportDataSource RD = new ReportDataSource();
        table = dt.Clone();
        var FechaInicio_ini = FechaInicio(CEV_FECHA_INICIO_ini.Value);
        var FechaInicio_fin = FechaFin(CEV_FECHA_INICIO_fin.Value);
        var FechaFin_ini = FechaInicio(CEV_FECHA_FIN_Ini.Value);
        var FechaFin_fin = FechaFin(CEV_FECHA_FIN_fin.Value);

        try
        {
            if (ddUsu.SelectedValue != "")
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in ddUsu.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected == true)
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt, int.Parse(item.Value),
                               FechaInicio_ini, FechaInicio_fin,
                              FechaFin_ini, FechaFin_fin,(txtParticipante.Value == "" ? " " : txtParticipante.Value));
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
                        {
                            table.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(ListItem item in ddUsu.Items)
                {
                    da.Fill(dt, int.Parse(item.Value == "" ? "0" : item.Value),
                              FechaInicio_ini, FechaInicio_fin,
                             FechaFin_ini, FechaFin_fin, (txtParticipante.Value == "" ? " " : txtParticipante.Value));
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
                    {
                        table.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                    }
                }
            }
            divReporte.Visible = true;

            RD.Value = table;
            RD.Name = "dbCalendarioEventos";
            rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RD);
            rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReporteCalendarioEventos.rdlc";
            rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Reportes\Calendario\ReporteCalendarioEventos.rdlc";
            rvReporteCalendarioEventos.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }            
    }
```

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgtBc.png)